# Why does giving a negative value in the CSS function "translateY()" transform the element up?

Tags: html, css

I am having CSS code to move up a div element on its y-axis whenever user hovers the mouse over the div element. This is the output currently:

Here is the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kGzklYwdku5LMokC6F4jfri5PMxrdUk/view?usp=sharing) depicting it.

This is the current HTML and CSS code to do it:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>This is an article and it has some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>This is an article and it has some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>This is an article and it has some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>This is an article and it has some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>This is an article and it has some content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: #777;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 12px;
}

.card:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -4rem;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1rem)
}
```

My question is why is it moving in the positive y-axis when I supply `-1rem` and vice versa.

Kindly comment if more information is required.

Comment: Just a tip: there's no need to share a video. You can share your HTML and CSS code as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: It makes sense here because you read a page from top to bot. Sometimes the y axis is pointing toward the bottom. In some matrix libraries the first element is the top left corner pixel and then when you increment the y value you get the next line.

Comment: did you read the documentation on how such function is defined?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL:DR;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY
It's the normal behavior `transform: translateY()`: positive value translate the element towards the bottom and negative value towards the top, and it makes sense because you read a page from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-rendering

The Y axis is going from top to bottom and the X axis from left to right. So using `translateY()` with a positive value will shift the element downwards and vice versa.